# Regex in jQuery Validation - Single quote issue in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex, jquery-validate

I have a regular expression to validate a password to contain numbers, lowercase and uppercase characters.

The one below works fine. But when I use this in jQuery Validation:

```
txtPassword: {
    required: true,
    regex: Regex
}

Regex = (?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:;/'?/&gt;.&lt;,])(?!.*\s).*$
```

But the issue is single quote `'` in Javascript. Can some body please help me to resolve this? Thankyou.

Comment: Your regex does not meet your password requirements hence it does not "work fine". For e.g., in the lookaheads you have the dot without a quantifier for the lower case check, upper case check and the number check. Moreover, I believe you also require atleast 1 special character in your password. **Hence clarify what pattern you want to match and give examples.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things that need to fixed in this regex:

- In your lookahead checks for the password, you have a period without
  a quantifier. Hence it will always fail that check. For e.g., for the
  number check, you should have `(?=.*\d)` instead of `(?=.\d)`.
- You do not escape characters with a forward-slash `/`, instead you
  use a backslash `\`. You have it escaped incorrectly with a
  forwardslash in the last character class.
- The only special characters or metacharacters inside a character
  class are the closing bracket (`]`), the backslash (`\`), the caret (`^`)
  and the hyphen (`-`). Hence it is not due to the single quote. The culprit is your caret which is not escaped.

Try this regex where the caret `^` is escaped instead of the quote `'`:

```
(?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%\^&*()_+}{":;'?/>.<,])(?!.*\s)^.*$
```

---

I am assuming by your question, you meant a Regexp to validate a password with:

- at least 1 number
- at least 1 lowerchase character
- at least 1 uppercase character
- at least 1 special character out of the set `!@#$%^&*()_+}{":;'?/>.<,`
- length between 8 and 16 characters

If this is true, please update your question with the clarified requirement.

---

Play with the regex in [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%3F%3D%5E.%7B8%2C16%7D%24%29%28%3F%3D.%2a%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D.%2a%5Ba-z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.%2a%5BA-Z%5D%29%28%3F%3D.%2a%5B!%40%23%24%25%5C%5E%26%2a%28%29_%2B%7D%7B%22%3A%3B%27%3F%2F%3E.%3C%2C%5D%29%28%3F!.%2a%5Cs%29%5E.%2a%24&input=P%40sSw0rD)

---

jQuery based code. Fiddle with this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kashkns/K3ZrM/):

```
var regex = /(?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%\^&*()_+}{":;'?/>.<,])(?!.*\s)^.*$/g;
//if(regex.test($('#txtPassword').val())){ alert('Match'); }else{alert('No Match')}
if (regex.test('P@sSw0rD')) {
    alert('Match');
} else {
    alert('No Match');
}​
```

Comment: Kash. Thanks for your immediate response. I tried the regex that you mentioned above, it works fine in Regexpal. But, it still fails all the time, when running in JQuery(asp.net page). When I used the Jquery Validator, the regex: "(?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%\^&*()_+}{":;'?/>.<,])(?!.*\s)^.*$" is breaking up till here regex: "(?=^.{8,16}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%\^&*()_+}{". So, I add backslash(\) infront of doublequote("). But still it fails all the time. Can't figure out what the reason is?

Comment: @user1678741 - You don't need a backslash for `"`   in a character class. Try the code in my answer. Use your password field in the way shown in commented code.