# Don't allow invalid characters to be pasted on textbox

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox that doesn't accept quotation marks (') and some other defined special characters.

How can I validate those invalid characters when they try to paste or drag string into my textbox using jquery?

Example:

I drag the string "tes't" to my textbox, it should only show "test" since ' is invalid. Is that possible?

Comment: so what has been tried. You might want to have a look at http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/form-validation-using-jquery-and-regular-expressions/

Comment: try to replace var str = "tes't" str.replace("'","")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/remove-quotes-from-textarea/1/edit

```
$('textarea').on('input', function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/'/g,"");
});
```

if you want to make sure NOT ANY special character is included you can do like:

```
this.value.replace(/[^\w]/g,"");
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/remove-quotes-from-textarea/2/edit)

Comment: .on('input') event seems not to work properly on quirks mode of IE9.
Initially, it works on my local machine but when I move it to our actual server which holds quirks as default mode, it fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is done by regular expression in js side.

> str = str.replace(/(['"])/g, "\$1"); 
>   ref( [jQuery: How to escape single and double quotes with backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491606/jquery-how-to-escape-single-and-double-quotes-with-backslash))

"Onblur" or "OnChange" event of textbox you validate this.

Or

Button click also check the same thing. (my suggestion is onblur of textbox)

Here is good example with single quote/double quote etc. Read the question/answer, Whatever you don't want , just remove.

[Regex in jQuery Validation - Single quote issue in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469106/regex-in-jquery-validation-single-quote-issue-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var lst = ["\"", "&", "'", "%"];
    $('#txt').on('input', function () {           
      var inputText = $(this).val();
      var index = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {                    
        index = $.inArray(inputText.charAt(i), lst);
        if (index >= 0) {
           var myregexp = new RegExp(lst[index], 'g');
           $(this).val($(this).val().replace(myregexp, ""));
        }
      }
    });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/j8jDy/4/)